# Dynamic Market Equilibrium: motivation for differential equations

Tags: macroeconomics, general-equilibrium, ode

I came across [this](https://masterofeconomics.org/2009/11/26/the-second-order-differential-equations-of-dynamic-market-equilibrium/) discussion, claiming supply and demand are expressible in terms of its price as $$Q_s=c_1+w_1P+u_1P'+v_1P'',\,Q_d=c_2+w_2P+u_2P'+v_2P''.$$Equating supply to demand for an equilibrium gives an ODE one can solve, but where do these formulae for $Q_s,\,Q_d$ come from?

I apologise if, contrary to the impression the page gives, these equations are not a mainstream model.

Answer (score 2):

As the link you provided mentions:

> "Differential equations can be used to include the dynamic aspects to
>   economics into a mathematical framework which takes into account the
>   volatility present in economics."

So the author does not derive the differential equations as the result of a theoretical model -the author just wants to obtain the movement through time of *equilibrium* price (the author assumes market-clearing), as a second order differential equation.

So it is a purely descriptive/forecasting exercise, devoid of any economic theory background. The author obtains the solution, which includes a number of coefficients to be determined, for which the author mentions

> "These values can be estimated using statistics and econometric
>   methods"

Some constraints on the parameters may come from observing the past price process (is it oscillating? around a trend or around an horizontal line? etc), and in the end, the hope is that we may obtain a good predictor for the price movements -again, without basing it on economic theory.